# Coldfusion8: how to create associative array?

Tags: arrays, coldfusion-8

i need to create a array of line items "arrayOfQuoteLineItem". in place of position value i have to associate name for position,how to do it in coldfusion8? i have seen some code on the "http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1676-Learning-ColdFusion-9-Delete-Array-Elements-With-ArrayDelete-.htm" for coldfusion9 but not for coldfusio8?

```
QuoteLineItem
   nmfcClass = "100"
   weight = "300"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associative arrays are called "structures" or "structs" in CF.  You can nest structs in arrays, or structs in structs, or whatever you need.

```
<cfset quoteLineItems = arrayNew(1) /> <!--- or <cfset quoteLineItems = [] /> --->
<!--- probably some looping code here --->
<cfset st = structNew() /> <!--- or <cfset st = {} /> --->
<cfset st.nmfcClass = 100 />
<cfset st.weight = 300 />
<cfset arrayAppend(quoteLineItems, st) />
<!--- end loop --->
```